# validating variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Hi i have a field in php that will be validated in javascript using i.e for emails

```
var emailRegex = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;
```

What i'm after is a validation check which will look for the 
first letter as a capital Q
then the next letters can be numbers only
then followed by a .
then two numbers only
and then an optional letter
i.e Q100.11 or Q100.11a

I must admit i look at the above email validation check and i have no clue how it works but it does ;)

many thanks for any help on this

Steve

Comment: are you looking for the regular expression to use, or the javascript, or both?

Comment: im after the regex for the match

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`var regex = /^Q[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}[a-z]?$/;`

`+` means one or more

the period must be escaped - `\.`

`[0-9]{2}` means 2 digits, same as `\d{2}`

`[a-z]?` means 0 or 1 letter

You can check your regex at http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Your dot will match any symbol, not just a dot. It should be a \. instead. Also, [a-z] does not include uppercase letters.

Comment: yeh, I see you need to `code` the line for the \ to show.  Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Hi thanks, the reg code actually only allows one letter at the end which i was after ;) thanks foson

Answer (score 2):

The `^` marks the beginning of the string, `$` matches the end of the string. In other words, the whole string should exactly match this regular expression.

- `[\w-\.]+`: I think you wanted to match letters, digits, dots and `-` only. In that case, the `-` should be escaped (`\-`): `[\w\-\.]+`. The plus-sign makes is match one or more times.
- `@`: a literal `@` match
- `([\w-]+\.)+` letters, digits and `-` are allowed one or more times, with a dot after it (between the parentheses). This may occur several times (at least once).
- `[\w-]{2,4}`: this should match the TLD, like `com`, `net` or `org`. Because a TLD can only contain letters, it should be replaced by `[a-z]{2,4}`. This means: lowercase letters may occur two till four times. Note that the TLD can be longer than 4 characters.

An regular expression which should follow the next rules:

- a capital `Q` (`Q`)
- followed by one or more occurrences of digits (`\d+`)
- a literal dot (`.`)
- two digits (`\d{2}`)
- one optional letter (`[a-z]?`)

Result:

```
var regex = /Q\d+\.\d{2}[a-z]?/;
```

If you need to match strings case-insensitive, add the `i` (case-**i**nsensitive) modifier:

```
var regex = /Q\d+\.\d{2}[a-z]?/i;
```

Validating a string using a regexp can be done in several ways, one of them:

```
if (regex.test(str)) {
   // success
} else {
   // no match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var emailRegex = /^Q\d+\.\d{2}[a-zA-Z]?@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$/;
var str = "Q100.11@test.com";
alert(emailRegex.test(str));
```

Comment: I'm guessing you might also include a sample of how to use it in JS.

Comment: Close but not quite. It's not * but ? right before the @. Also there was no case given on the last letter, so better make it both. Lastly, 4 letters are not enought for TLDs (museum comes to mind) but they are letters only.

`/^Q\d+\.\d{2}[a-zA-Z]?@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$/`